Create Custom Azure Policy - DeployIfNoExists effect to add specific tag (Environment:Cloud) to newly created resources
We have a requirement to create Azure policy with DeployIfNoExists effect with specific tag for newly created resources. But, I`m kind of stuck, I have tried to rewrite modify built in one policy - no luck, have tried to rewrite existing builtin DeployIfNoExists policies, again no luck, getting errors over and over again.
Could you provide some guidance or maybe similar samples on how can I achieve it.
Would be very grateful!
Happy upcoming holidays!
[Update, code that I`ve tried]:
``
{
  "mode": "Indexed",
  "policyRule": {
    "if": {
      "field": "[concat('tags[', parameters('tag_BuildBy'), ']')]",
      "exists": "false"
    },
    "then": {
      "effect": "[parameters('effect')]",
      "details": {
        "type": "Microsoft.Resources/tags",
        "roleDefinitionIds": [
          "/providers/Microsoft.Authorization/roleDefinitions/b24988ac-6180-42a0-ab88-20f7382dd24c"
        ],
        "deployment": {
          "properties": {
            "mode": "incremental",
            "template": {
              "$schema": "http://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
              "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
              "resources": [
                {
                  "type": "Microsoft.Resources/tags",
                  "apiVersion": "2019-10-01",
                  "name": "[concat(parameters('tagResourceId'))]",
                  "properties": {
                    "tags": {
                      "[parameters('tag_BuildBy')]": "hello"
                    }
                  }
                }
              ]
            },
            "parameters": {
              "tagResourceId": {
                "value": "[concat(resourceGroup().id, '/providers/Microsoft.Resources/tags/default')]"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "parameters": {
    "effect": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "Effect",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
      },
      "allowedValues": [
        "DeployIfNotExists",
        "Disabled"
      ],
      "defaultValue": "DeployIfNotExists"
    },
    "tag_BuildBy": {
      "type": "String",
      "metadata": {
        "displayName": "build",
        "description": "Enable or disable the execution of the policy"
      }
    }
  }
}
``


Have you tried any policies? If yes, please share any errors you are encountering.

@VenkatV
Have tried something like above, but it indicates in policy that:
No resources found
